# Pair an Android Wear watch and Raspberry Pi via bluetooth

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-bluetooth

I would like to pair and Android Wear watch like Moto 360 or G watch R with a Raspberry Pi via bluetooth to receive notifications of various type and and accept or discard them pressing a button on the watch (writing a custom app). Is it possible? Reading http://www.android.com/wear/ it seems to be possible only to connect the watch with an Android phone.

Comment: Any luck/progress with your project?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the Android wear watch (Moto 360) uses Bluetooth Low Energy technology whose API is given at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html .

On Raspberry-Pi side, you need to use a bluetooth to serial adapter. An example of such Bluetooth Low Energy adapter can be seen at http://www.ti.com/devnet/docs/catalog/endequipmentproductfolder.tsp?actionPerformed=productFolder&productId=13700.

Reading documentation of both can help you get your project working :)